# WSO2 problems after changing Certificate

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have wso2 Identity server in my TEST environment. Team has been using it for some months and lot of users and roles are created.
Recently we have got CA certificates and installed it.
After that we cant add users saying the problem Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name.
Looks like new certificate is the problem.
What is the work around to get around this problem without rebuilding environment?Data is not of much importance.Can clear all the users and roles.

What are the best approaches to over come this?

Comment: Have you resolved it? Which path did you choose as a solution?

Comment: did you face this?what error are you getting?